# Google Meet Crashes "Owner Asynchronously disposed" message in console

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-meet

[image]

Recently I am facing an issue with google meet in firefox as well as chrome. In the google meet call the other person cannot hear me and after a few seconds the call disconnects saying network issues.

1] Console shows the above error message.

2] There are no 400 or 500 responses in the Network tab.

3] Happens across both my systems. Pfsense is a firewall I have which I cannot turn off.

Has anybody faced this issue or let me know what can be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after purging cloudflare-warp, removing system wide certificates from /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra and reinstalling the latest version (at this point 2022.7.x)

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago I had same issue with windows/linux clients behind an enterprise network, using http proxy.
Workaround applied was forcing default mic/cam chrome permissions to "ask(default)", not "allow". Haven't found root cause yet. let me know if it was effective. regards.